# How to access JavaScript element style from styles.CSS, Django

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I have this JavaScript code that does createElement, but how can I style it from my separate CSS file?

JavaScript

```
emails.forEach(function(email) {
const element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = email.sender + ' ' + email.subject + ' ' + email.timestamp
document.querySelector('#email-container').append(element);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="email-container">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#email-container .element{
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're styling it that way, then you expect the div to have class `element`. So you just need one extra line to add that class to the element. Full code here:

```
emails.forEach(function(email) {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.classList.add('element');
  element.innerHTML = email.sender + ' ' + email.subject + ' ' + email.timestamp
  document.querySelector('#email-container').append(element);
});
```

Comment: I have added the line and edited the CSS to #email-container .element it does the work, do you suggest any other solution that is better used in real-world projects?

Comment: Not really, using a class seems fine - you usually use classes and/or IDs for CSS styles, and since you are adding several different elements here you can't use an ID (as they need to be unique in the document).

Comment: I see, Thank you!